# Extract data based on second column

Tags: linux, command-line, python, r

Now I have a file format like

```
ACTG,CD1,234
BGTY,CD2,561
CFRT,CD3,27
DGTY,CD4,45
EYTG,CD5,23
FJUI,CD1,78
GYHJ,CD2,89
HYHG,CD3,107
IUHJHU,CD4,55
JMJGT,CD5,77
```

I want my output file like:

```
CD1,ACTG,234
CD1,FJUI,78
```

Can anybody tell me what the linux command will be for doing this?

Comment: Welcome to U/L! I noticed that you cross-posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56351661/1944384). Unfortunately, cross-posting on multiple sites is discouraged, and will result in the question being closed.

Comment: The cross-post has since been deleted.

Comment: Wendy, can you use some words to explain the transformation you're expecting, just so that Answerers don't have to guess themselves?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," } $2 == "CD1" { print $2, $1, $3 }' inputfile
```

Comment: The second column is not "1" exactly, I just use 1 to represent the data, the exact data is "CD127", I replace "1" to CD127 in the command you gave but did not work

Comment: And my input file actually not tab separate it's separate by "," and I updated the file format at this answer.

Comment: @WendyHuang With the field separator changed and quotes, try `awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} $2 == "CD1" { print $2, $1, $3 }' inputfile`. I'm an awk noob, but it seems to do the job.

Comment: @Freddy I tried your command, it did extract the row that second column is "CD1" but it didn't print out the third column in the result.

Comment: @WendyHuang Hmm, I can't reproduce it. Any difference if you use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=","} $2 == "CD1" { print $2, $1, $3 }' inputfile`? This is the same command, just different syntax. And if you remove `$2 == "CD1"` it should just swap column one and two of your data. If that doesn't help we'll have to wait for an expert...

Comment: @Freddy no it didn't work. I post this question on Stackoverflow, hope can get answer, that's weird.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the new example input and desired output.